# WebRTC Peer to Peer Connection

Tags: c++, multithreading, webrtc

I am Implementing a WebRTC Peer to Peer connection for Audio Calling using C++.

I have two threads `_worker_thread` and `_signaling_thread`. Now when I try to create `_peerConnectionFactory` by calling the method `webrtc::CreatePeerConnectionFactory()`, my app crashes. How can I make it work?

```
_signaling_thread.reset(new rtc::Thread());
if(!_signaling_thread->Start())
{
    printf("_signaling_thread is Failed");
    return;
}
_worker_thread.reset(new rtc::Thread());
if (!_worker_thread->Start()) {
    printf( "_worker_thread is Failed");
    return;
}

_peerConnectionFactory = webrtc::CreatePeerConnectionFactory(_worker_thread.get(),_signaling_thread.get(),NULL,NULL,NULL);
```

This is the backtrace I am getting

```
* thread #15: tid = 0x17e516, 0x00000001008d5674 MyAPP`rtc::MessageQueue::Get(rtc::Message*, int, bool) + 816, stop reason =  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x100000038)                                              
* frame #0: 0x00000001008d5674 MyAPP`rtc::MessageQueue::Get(rtc::Message*, int, bool) + 816
frame #1: 0x00000001008e5fb0 MyAPP`rtc::Thread::ProcessMessages(int) + 100
frame #2: 0x00000001008e5e44 MyAPP`rtc::Thread::PreRun(void*) + 88
frame #3: 0x0000000199337b3c libsystem_pthread.dylib`_pthread_body + 156
frame #4: 0x0000000199337aa0 libsystem_pthread.dylib`_pthread_start + 1
```

Comment: There is no question in the post, yet somehow it was upvoted 2 times. I wonder who did the upvoting and why.

Comment: @SergeyA I need the solution that why its not working out for me, is there any way to solve this issue? And what else do you need to know please let me know.

Comment: It isn't clear how the backtrace relates to the code posted. What happens at offset 816 from `rtc::MessageQueue::Get`? Why and when is that function called? From the `pthread` lines, I'm guessing this is happening in one of the background threads. Can you tell which?

Comment: @AustinMullins - 'rtc::MessageQueue::Get'  this method get called when my signaling thread starts. And yes ,there is a backgroud thread which is invoking this above mentioned code basically this set of code is for making Peer to Peer  Webrtc connection.

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the Get method? That's where the segfault (Bad Access) is.

Comment: @AustinMullins-Its a part Of WebRTC delivered library .We just need to start the threads from our end .My problem is similar to the problem discussed here [link](https://code.google.com/p/webrtc/issues/detail?id=4196).The problem is because of the WebRtc threads.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After taking a look at the PeerConnection samples located inside the WebRTC's source code, I always initialize SSL modules before creating the threads like this:

```
bool Core::Init() {
  rtc::InitializeSSL();
  rtc::InitRandom(rtc::Time());
  rtc::ThreadManager::Instance()->WrapCurrentThread();

  _signalingThread = new rtc::Thread();
  _workerThread = new rtc::Thread();

  _signalingThread->SetName("signaling_thread", NULL);
  _workerThread->SetName("worker_thread", NULL);

  if (!_signalingThread->Start() || !_workerThread->Start()) {
    return false;
  }

  _peerConnectionFactory =
      webrtc::CreatePeerConnectionFactory(_signalingThread,
                                          _workerThread,
                                          NULL, NULL, NULL).release();

  return true;
}
```

Comment: Why do you call `release()` on the peerConnectionFactory?

Comment: Yes, why do you call .release() on peerConnectionFactory object?

Comment: @Phylliida @JSON returned value was `std::unique_ptr`, so he wants to take ownership of the pointer