# Mutex failure in sample_test_webrtc when compiled with clang on Linux

Tags: c++, linux, clang, webrtc, mutex

The webrtc repository has an internal sample application, named sample_test_webrtc (the folder's name where it's implementation resides). I built it using gn and ninja and it works.

Then I took that code separately, statically linked it with libwebrtc.a that I generated using the command below:

```
./buildtools/linux64/gn gen out/Default --target_cpu=x64 --target_os="linux" --host_os="linux" --host_cpu="x64" --args="is_debug=false rtc_include_tests=false libyuv_include_tests=false rtc_build_examples=false 
is_component_build=false use_rtti=true use_custom_libcxx=false rtc_enable_protobuf=false clang_use_chrome_plugins=false rtc_ios_macos_use_opengl_rendering=false rtc_libvpx_build_vp9=false archive_seed_corpus=false 
toolkit_views=false enable_iterator_debugging=false enable_libaom=false rtc_build_tools=false" --complete_static_lib
```

In order to separately compile and link this sample program with the such generated library, I used the following makefile:

```
CC = clang++
CFLAGS = -Wall -g -DWEBRTC_POSIX -std=c++17 -stdlib=libstdc++

SRC_DIR = $(PWD)
SRC_FILES = $(wildcard $(SRC_DIR)/*.cpp) $(wildcard $(SRC_DIR)/*/*.cpp) 

OBJ_DIR = $(PWD)/Obj
OBJ_FILES = $(patsubst $(SRC_DIR)/%.cpp, $(OBJ_DIR)/%.o, $(SRC_FILES)) 
ADDITIONAL_OBJ_FILES = $(PWD)/Deps/*.o

INCLUDES_PATH = -I. -I/home/stefan/webrtc-l4s/webrtc_native/m104/src -I../../third_party/webrtc/buildtools/third_party -I../../third_party/webrtc/third_party/abseil-cpp/ 
LIBRARIES_PATH = -L../../third_party/webrtc/buildtools/third_party -L/home/stefan/webrtc-l4s/webrtc_native/m104/src/out/Default2/obj
#use portable -pthread instead of classic -lpthread
LIBS = -pthread -ldl -lX11 -L. -lwebrtc  

BIN_DIR = $(PWD)/Bin
TARGET_BINARY = $(BIN_DIR)/demoWebrtc.bin

all: $(TARGET_BINARY)
    @echo "[Build log] Target binary successfully built!"

$(TARGET_BINARY): $(OBJ_FILES)
    @echo "[Build log] Linking..." 
    @echo $(ADDITIONAL_OBJ_FILES)
    $(CC) $(LIBRARIES_PATH) -o $@ $^ $(LIBS)
    @echo "[Build log] Program linked!" 

$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o: $(SRC_DIR)/%.cpp
    @echo "[Build log] Compiling..."
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(INCLUDES_PATH) -c $< -o $@
    @echo "[Build log] File" $< "compiled!"  

clean:
    rm -rf $(OBJ_DIR)/*.o
    rm -rf $(BIN_DIR)/*.bin
```

That said, my program is successfully compiled and linked, with the executable `demoWebrtc.bin` being generated. Nonetheless, when I run it, it fails with the following error:

```
demoWebrtc.bin: ../nptl/pthread_mutex_lock.c:81: __pthread_mutex_lock: Assertion `mutex->__data.__owner == 0' failed.
Aborted (core dumped)
```

I examined the error and it indicates a thread aims to acquire again a mutex it already had locked, in method bool SequenceCheckerImpl::IsCurrent() const from src/rtc_base/synchronization/sequence_checker_internal.cc file, that can be found in webrtc's repository: https://webrtc.googlesource.com/src/+/refs/heads/main/rtc_base/synchronization/sequence_checker_internal.cc. However, I am 100% sure the problem is not the webrtc implementation. As I use the same test application (same source code), I am also quite sure it is not the problem with the code using the library.

The code for sample_test_webrtc can also be found in another repository: https://github.com/MemeTao/webrtc-native-examples/tree/master/src/video-channel. But, in my case, it was included in the webrtc repository I pulled.

My question is: why does not this error occur in the first case, when I built the program using gn and ninja, that works smoothly? Or what I miss in my second case, thus leading to the mutex error?

Later edit: since it is a threading issue, I found this topic [WebRTC Peer to Peer Connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32742170/webrtc-peer-to-peer-connection). I applied the proposed solution, but it did not solve my issue.

Comment: Please extract a [mcve], I'm sure it would answer your questions on the way. That said, if a mutex is already owned by a thread, you could look through the stack trace to find out where it is already locked.